# How to override ListAdpter's behavior?

Tags: android, bluetooth, listadapter

I am working on a simple Bluetooth application for android and I have a ListActivity that
displays all the device I've found.

So I have a ListAdapter like this:

```
deviceNameListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,devices);
```

and it is set to be displayed.

However, the ListActivity displays the device's address instead of the device's name. I am guessing the ListActivity will call the item in devices's `.toString()` method when it displays the list of devices. I am just thinking is there anyway I can change this behaviour? 
The BluetoothDevice class have a method called `.getName()` which is what should be called.

Cheers!

Comment: Use BaseAdapter, this way ou can manage everything the way you want

Comment: @Yume117 So I have to come up with my own adapter myself by extending it and implement the getView() method?

Comment: With base adapter it is as simple. Your create your class WhateverAdapter.java that extends BaseAdapter. This implement all the required methods. And yes in GetView() you just have to control what each cells will display.

Comment: @Yume117 Sorry to bother but How do you control the view? by using a new xml file? What should the xml file contains? THX.

Comment: You create an xml file for each diferent type of cells, and an xml file for the layout with the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemple of adapter class:

```
public class AdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {


     private List _list;

     public AdapterDirectories(List list){
          // Constructor with good parameters
          _list = list;
     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return _list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        CellHolder cellHolder = null;
        // get
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            cellHolder = new CellHolder();
            cellHolder.textTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            view.setTag(cellHolder);
        }
        else {
            cellHolder = (CellHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // set
        cellHolder.textTitle.setText("");
        return view;
    }

    public class CellHolder {
        public TextView     textTitle;
    }
}
```

setting the adapter to the list view :

```
_listView.setAdapter(_adapter);
```