# Setting the getItem on a custom adapter

Tags: android, custom-adapter

Because I am using a custom listView adapter for my applicaiton, some of the default methods are overridden. The problem occurs when I call the `getItem(position)` method of the adapter. Because this method is overridden, my attempt to find out the selected items are returned as null.

The custom adapter overrides the method as follows:

```
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
```

The call for getting the selected items:

```
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // retrieve selected items and print them out
    ArrayListAdapter adapter = (ArrayListAdapter) Allprojects.this.getListAdapter();
    SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();            
    for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++){               
        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
            String selectedItem = (String) adapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
            message.append(selectedItem + "\n");
        }
    }           
    Toast.makeText(Allprojects.this, message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // close action mode
    mode.finish();
    return false;
}
```

How do I now override the getItem(position) method such that I get the selected items. Please do help.

Comment: You should use BaseAdapter... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633291/how-to-override-listadpters-behavior/18636098#18636098

Comment: @Yume117 I am using the BaseAdapter

Comment: Sorry didn't comprehend this xp

Comment: @Yume117 but thanks your reference help too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using BaseAdapter, you must have a List (or some other Collection) of items within it, right? just use

```
return list.get(position);
```